# ncurses in a multithreaded application

Tags: c, multithreading, ncurses

I have a multi threaded application which uses ncurses on a single thread to report information to the user. My code basically looks like this:

```
const unsigned int      refresh_cycle = 180;
unsigned int            refresh_count = refresh_cycle;

while(killswitch != 1) {

    if (refresh_count >= refresh_cycle) {
        // critical section which obtains some data worked on by a thread. only does this once every refresh cycle times
        // mtx lock, fetch, mtx unlock 
        refresh_count = 0;
    }
    refresh_count++;

    // get input

    // draw some stuff

    // refresh
}
```

What I notice is that the ncurses window gets refreshed lots and lots of times. Way more than is really needed for a user who could probably get by with only 15-30 refreshes in a second.

But now I am worrying this might 'steal' unnecesary processing power from one of the threads that is doing work. Is this a reasonable assertion?

Should I build in a sort of frame limiter with `usleep()` or would that be going overboard?

Comment: Can't you just use a condition variable to let the curses thread know when something's changed and a refresh is needed, and just have it sit waiting on that? If the data is just constantly updating, then yes, just sleeping for a while would be fine.

Comment: no I can`t user interaction can happen in between changes.

Comment: Then the easiest way is probably `select()` with a suitably small timeout. When `select()` returns, either because there is user input or because it timed out, do a refresh at that point.

Comment: ah didn`t think of that, never even used it. such a usefull tool! add it as an answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments, if in between the refreshes you need to deal with user input, then the easiest way is probably to call `select()` on `STDIN_FILENO` with a suitably small timeout. When `select()` returns, either because there is user input or because it timed out, do a refresh at that point.

Here's an example that'll let you see how to set this up, and shows when when and how many times `select()` is returning so you can visualize what's going on. Try letting it sit and run for a while, and then try holding down a key, and watch how the `select() has returned [n] times` message behaves in each case. The comments in the code explain what's happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

/*  struct to store curses info for cleanup  */

struct curinfo {
    WINDOW * main_window;
    int old_cursor;
};

/*  curses helper functions  */

void start_curses(struct curinfo * info);
void stop_curses(struct curinfo * info);

/*  main function  */

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    /*  Set default timeout  */

    int secs = 0;
    int usecs = 500000;

    /*  Set timeout based on command line args, if provided  */

    if ( argc > 1 ) {
        if ( !strcmp(argv[1], "veryshort") ) {
            secs = 0;
            usecs = 200000;
        }
        else if ( !strcmp(argv[1], "short") ) {
            secs = 1;
            usecs = 0;
        }
        else if ( !strcmp(argv[1], "medium") ) {
            secs = 2;
            usecs = 0;
        }
        else if ( !strcmp(argv[1], "long") ) {
            secs = 5;
            usecs = 0;
        }
    }

    struct curinfo cinfo;
    start_curses(&cinfo);

    int input = '0';        /*  Set to something printable  */
    int num_sel = 0;        /*  Number of times select() has returned  */

    while ( input != 'q' && input != 'Q' ) {

        /*  Output messages  */

        mvprintw(3, 3, "select() has returned %d times", num_sel);
        mvprintw(4, 3, "Last character input was %c", input);
        mvprintw(5, 3, "Press 'q' to quit");
        refresh();

        /*  select() modifies the fd_sets passed to it,
         *  so zero and set them prior to each call.     */

        fd_set fds;
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);

        /*  Same deal for the struct timeval, select() may
         *  modify it, it may not, so recreate to be portable.  */

        struct timeval tv;
        tv.tv_sec = secs;
        tv.tv_usec = usecs;

        /*  Store the return so we can check it  */

        int status = select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        /*  Check for error  */

        if ( status == -1 ) {

            /*  select() returned with an error.  */

            if ( errno != EINTR ) {

                /*  If interrupted by a signal, no problem,
                 *  keep going. Otherwise, let's just quit.  */

                stop_curses(&cinfo);
                perror("error calling select()");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
        else if ( FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds) ) {

            /*  Only call getch() if input is ready.
             *  getch() will not block when we do it this way.  */

            if ( (input = getch()) == ERR ) {
                stop_curses(&cinfo);
                fprintf(stderr, "ERR returned from getch()\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }

        /*  Increment number of times select() has returned  */

        ++num_sel;
    }

    stop_curses(&cinfo);

    return 0;
}

/*  Starts curses and populates the passed struct  */

void start_curses(struct curinfo * info)
{
    if ( (info->main_window = initscr()) == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error calling initscr()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    timeout(0);
    raw();
    nonl();
    noecho();
    info->old_cursor = curs_set(0);
    refresh();
}

/*  Stops curses and cleans up  */

void stop_curses(struct curinfo * info)
{
    delwin(info->main_window);
    curs_set(info->old_cursor);
    endwin();
    refresh();
}
```

Comment: it seems `select()` only returns if I set the timeout low enough. this is very weird... I cannot ask another question within 90 minutes. Here is a notepad link to code where the error occurs. If the timeout is high enough the weird behavior does not occur. Here is a compilable exampe: http://shrib.com/0yKkHary

Comment: @rowan.G: See updated question for an example. Your code has some issues where you're not resetting the `fd_set` each time, and you're calling `getch()` regardless of whether `select()` indicated input was ready. You're also not calling `refresh()` anywhere in your loop, which probably isn't helping. See how you get on with my sample code.

Comment: thank you, I didn't realize I have te reset `FD_SET()` each time I call `select()`. `getch()` implicitly calls `refresh()`